# How to receive and show all key/value pairs in android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I currently have an app that essentially let's the user enter text in an editText. And when the user clicks the button "create", it creates a textView with the text of what was in the editText(the user can make as many as he or she wants). Simultaneously, I have a sharedPreference that will save the String entered by the user when a textView is made. My app then allows the user to go onto another activities page that has them doing something else with each piece of text they entered on the previous page. So, I need my app to retain the textViews that were created. This is why I have the sharedPreference saving the text of each textView. My question is, how can I take each String saved into my sharedPreference, and then put each onto a textView that will be created when the activity starts. I won't know the names of the key for each value, because it will be whatever the user typed in, and I won't know how many pieces of text the user will make, because there isn't a limit or minimum to how many he or she can make.

Comment: or use SQLite. it fits better to the requirements of ur application

Comment: If you're using "whatever the user typed in" as the key, what happens if they enter the same String twice?

Comment: I'm using an SQLite for other data that is more hefty, while this data I plan on deleting whenever the app closes. So would it be smart to make a whole new other SQLite just for this?

Comment: @MikeM. I will set up some code so that my app catches this, and they wont be able to do this

Comment: Gotcha. I was just pointing it out. I would also mention that, using this method, the order you get the entries in isn't always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Set<String> keys = pref.getAll().keySet();
```

to get a set of all the keys in the shared preference.  Then display them however you want (a listView sounds like a good idea).

Comment: But once I recieve them all, how would I set each as a textView's text. Since there could be a lot, I guessing a loop is required.

Comment: I think you should research what a listview is

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> keylist = pref.getAll().keySet();
for (String s : keylist) {
//Use sharedpreference with s as the key and get the values
}
```